# Global IP sourced on my INSIDE interface to another global IP on OUTSIDE interface

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, syslog

I have a Cisco ASA that gives me some sylogs that I do not understand. My INSIDE interface is where all my private IP addresses reside for the enterprise i work for. My OUTSIDE interface is what has my public IP address block assigned to it. I often see the following logs which I do not understand, a routable IP address is being sourced on the INSIDE interface with a destination to another routable public IP on the OUTSIDE interface. Any ideas?

None of the IP addresses on these logs belong to me or are assign to any of my devices.

```
08:24:02.418:Jun 08 08:24:02 EDT: %ASA--4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from INSIDE:123.201.138.87/20219 to OUTSIDE:209.118.224.55/2323 with different initial sequence number
08:24:02.384:Jun 08 08:24:02 EDT: %ASA--4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from INSIDE:123.201.138.87/20219 to OUTSIDE:209.118.224.55/2323 with different initial sequence number
08:24:02.351:Jun 08 08:24:02 EDT: %ASA--4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from INSIDE:123.201.138.87/20219 to OUTSIDE:209.118.224.55/2323 with different initial sequence number
```

Comment: I would attempt to track down that IP.  You haven't told us anything about your topology, but I would do a packet capture on the ASA to verify the message and learn the source MAC address.  You'll have to keep working backwards until you find the source.

Comment: It's keeps happening with different IP addresses. Traceroutes leave my ISP but they do not complete. My ASA is my edge device. Behind it I have layer 3 switches & some routers that connect my different site wans.

Comment: You will not be able to use traceroute or ARP to find them.  Wireshark is your best bet.

Comment: use of TPC 2323 suggest that you have a machine infected by a botnet. You should find the originating machine ASAP, disconnect it from the network, and check it for infection

Comment: Good point. The thought did cross my mind that we had a botnet/virus issue......My ASA connects to a Layer 3 Switch (INSIDE interface) which is my core distribution switch. 90% of traffic that goes to the internet on my network goes through this switch. I'll get wireshark started and look for these static IPs, I noticed the same 2 destinations though. 69.94.242.149/23  and  209.118.224.48/22. btw, i have a barracuda webfilter between the L3 and ASA.

Comment: You can also block outbound traffic to those addresses in order to prevent the infected device(s) from phoning home while you track this down.

Comment: once i did that my users could not browse the internet. I suspect the public IP's are coming from my barracuda webfilter. They are not coming from anything downstream. Packet captures have not cached anything with a source IP that is not private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I believe I found the problem. My remote sites have their own routers with their own internet connection. We don,t really use it for anything other than an IPSEC tunnel back to HQ to use as a backup WAN link..

I use EIGRP to build my route tables, so these routers at my remote sites happen to not have a static default route. So anytime their public IP is pinged, scanned, and so forth, the replies are going out using the default route learned by EIGRP, which goes over our WAN line to my CORE switch then out to the internet through my ASA firewall.

As soon as I add a static default route at each remote site the problem, so far, goes away.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so it doesn't keep popping up here looking for an answer.

Comment: i gotta wait 22hrs.

Answer (score 1):

When a public IP address shows up inside your private network you should track it down. Check the ARP table on the ASA whether the source is connected directly or work from there to the source router. Once you've got the source MAC you work through your switches to find the source port.

Comment: checked my arp tables on my routers and Layer 3 switches, nothing.

Comment: Especially if this is just intermittent, set up a packet trace as Ron suggested. Once you have a packet you can track it down.